# How can I find my Nameservers on amazon ec2 server?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I recently got an Amazon EC2 micro server to learn how to use nodejs. (I am not servers savvy BTW).

I managed to install everything and having nodejs running on the server and running their example script.

on Amazon I set the server security group to allow all / icmap - all/ tcp - 0-65535/ ssh/HTTP/HTTPS so basically everything is allowed more or less.

My question is how can I find my nameserver so I can use them on a new domain that I've bought.

I might be completely wrong and missing many steps if so. Do you know of a good tutorial on how to do that?

Thanks and sorry for the general question.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is point your domain to your new server.

You can do a couple of things in your domain registrar (where you bought your domain)

1. Add an A PTR record on your domain to point to the IP address of the server.
2. Add a CNAME record to point to the EC2 DNS name of your instance.

You can find the IP address and EC2 DNS name of your instance on the EC2 console:

[image: DNS Names and IP Address]

Comment: Thank you, helped me a lot. When setting the CNAME, it has to give a prefix name, such as `dns.edu3d.co.` Does this matter? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup your domain name on Amazon's Route 53 DNS service in order to use their nameservers. Check out the link on how to retrieve the nameservers: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/GetInfoAboutHostedZone.html

Comment: I see.  thanks for the answer rico and owais. a little question, when i visit the page in a nomral browser while the node server runs. shouldn't i get the hello world ? instead i am get Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at

Comment: @NetaMeta Is node running on port 80?

Comment: If the node server is not running on port 80, you need to explicitly specify the port like IP:PORT. What port are you running it on?

Comment: nope could not get it to work on port 80 and not is running on 1337 or 8000 right now, and both of them when i enter the url in the browser i set it as : ip:port